# How can I change pointer locations setting in developer options from adb shell?

Tags: adb, shell

I need to be able to select and deselect "pointer locations" from the developer options menu using adb.  `adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.DevelopmentSettings`, but once I'm there I can't figure out how to select and de-select pointer locations.

I tried just using shell keyevent 'xx' to move the focus, but it seems problematic and unreliable.  Is there a simple set of commands that will allow me to just jump to the selection?

Answer (score 10):

To enable **Pointer locations**, the command is:

```
adb shell settings put system pointer_location 1
```

Change `1` to `0` to disable it.

Enter `adb shell settings` to understand its usage and what the aforesaid command is doing.

Comment: adb shell settings put system pointer_location 1
/system/bin/sh: settings: not found

Comment: Are you using an Android earlier than Android 4.2.1? `settings` command was introduced starting from Android 4.2.1.

Comment: Thanks :) We're using 4.1.1 but will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @Firelord I'm trying these commands, but they don't affect Tinder on Androd for example: `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb -s 2C051FDH3002LA shell appops set com.google.android.gms android:mock_location allow

~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb -s 2C051FDH3002LA shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.GEO_LOCATION --es "lat" "38.6979" --es "long" "-9.2064" --ei "error" "10"
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.GEO_LOCATION flg=0x400000 (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0`

Comment: @EladBenda hi. I don't think your command applies to either the question or my answer. Consider creating a question instead and add as much details as you have.

Comment: @Firelord I have https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/252657/does-one-geo-location-broadcast-should-persist-mock-location-or-should-it-be-s