# Should one `geo location broadcast` persist mock location or should it be sent several times?

Tags: applications, adb, geolocation, location-services

I connected my android 14 (non jail broken) phone to my laptop.
Enabled usb debugging, and ran these commands.

```
`~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb -s 2C051FDH3002LA shell appops set com.google.android.gms android:mock_location allow

~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb -s 2C051FDH3002LA shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.GEO_LOCATION --es "lat" "38.6979" --es "long" "-9.2064" --ei "error" "10"
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.GEO_LOCATION flg=0x400000 (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0`
```

It doesn't affect `Tinder` application. And I wondered if in general one `geo location broadcast` should persist mock location or should it be sent several times?
Does a